# CheckBoxList Items Alignment

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I know this is a rather simple question, but I can't seem to properly align my checkboxlist.

I want the label on the left of the checkboxes, but still have the checkboxes aligned (see example below). Tried TextAlign="Left", but that made the checkboxlist items align by the text, not the checkboxes. I also tried using right alignment in my table The current result with the code below looks like the following:

```
       Item 1 [ ]
      Another Item [ ]
      Yet Another Item [ ]
      Last Item [ ]
```

Markup:

```
   <tr align="right" valign="top">
    <td align="right"><asp:CheckBoxList ID="Item1" runat="server" enabled="false" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" style="font-size: x-small;" TextAlign="Left"/>
   </td>
   <td align="right"><asp:CheckBoxList ID="Another Item" runat="server" enabled="false" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" style="font-size: x-small" />
   </td>
   </tr>
```

I would like the result to look like the following:

```
            Item 1 [ ]
      Another Item [ ]
  Yet Another Item [ ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a general comment... you would benefit greatly (in a number of ways) from using [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Css) instead of the mix of HTML and ASP.NET properties you're currently using for styling.

Comment: Also just a general comment... ID's must be one word. It doesn't take spaces

Comment: You show `CheckBoxList` elements in your markup, though it seems like you are wanting just single `CheckBox` elements. Is that a typo? Otherwise you need to first look there for your styling problems, as `CheckBoxList` will in fact render out html markup for `<input>` and `<label>` elements within a `<table>`.

Comment: My fault for being unclear. I'm dealing with two CheckBoxLists that have items arranged like in my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a CheckBoxList like this:

```
  <div style="text-align: right">
       <asp:CheckBoxList TextAlign="Left" runat="server" >
          <asp:ListItem Text = "foo" />
          <asp:ListItem Text = "bar" />
       </asp:CheckBoxList>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
<ul style="text-align:right; width:200px;">
    <li>Item 1 <input type="checkbox" value="Item1" name="group" /></li>
    <li>Another Item <input type="checkbox" value="Item2" name="group" /></li>
    <li>And another one <input type="checkbox" value="Item3" name="group" /></li>
</ul>
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CNuaN/)